# I encountered a problem in the process of integrating mybatis in using SpringBoot2

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

This is my error message when I start the project

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-05T18:47:51.471+08:00 ERROR 26348 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bookMapper in com.yzd.boot.service.BookService required a bean of type 'com.yzd.boot.mapper.BookMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.yzd.boot.mapper.BookMapper' in your configuration.
```

I'm trying to use bookMapper to look up book information based on Id, but the project shows that the BookMapper component cannot be found

Here's the code for my Mapper interface

```
@Mapper
public interface BookMapper {
  public Book getBook(Integer bookId);
}
```

BookMapper.xml Code

```
<mapper namespace="com.yzd.boot.mapper.BookMapper">
<!--    public Book getBook(Integer bookId);-->
    <select id="getBook" resultType="com.yzd.boot.bean.Book">
        select * from t_book where book_id = #{bookId}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Service layer code

```
@Service
public class BookService {
  @Autowired
  private BookMapper bookMapper;

  public Book getBook(Integer bookId){
    Book book = bookMapper.getBook(bookId);
    return book;
  }
}
```

Controller layer code

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
  @Autowired
  private BookService bookService;
  

  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping("/acct")
  public Book getBook(@RequestParam("id") Integer id){
    Book book = bookService.getBook(id);
    return book;
  }

}
```

application.yaml code

```
#Two rules of MyBatis
mybatis:
  config-location: classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml
  mapper-locations: classpath:mybatis/mapper/*.xml
```

I've made three attempts, but none of them have worked.

1. I tried to annotate the startup item with @MapperScan, but it still produces the reported error

   This is an error message.

   ```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookMapper' defined in file [D:\code-storage\idea\java\boot02-web-dev\target\classes\com\yzd\boot\mapper\BookMapper.class]: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
   ```

   The code shows that I need sqlSessionFactory or sqlSessionTemplate but isn't that automatically configured by springBoot, I just configured the datasource and connection driver in pom.xml and application.yaml.
2. I looked at the files in the target and found that the Mapper file exists, but I still can't inject it into the BookService.
3. I tried adding the @Repository annotation to the mapper interface, but still no luck.

Comment: To use Spring Boot 2.x, Spring version must be 5.x, not 6.x. Please read these docs as well : [mybatis-spring-boot](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/),  [mybatis-spring](https://mybatis.org/spring/). I would recommend making small changes one by one to a simple skeleton project (e.g. the `_spring-boot` in this [repo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues)) rather than starting from scratch. It's not easy to fix already-messed-up spring project. We also have more complex [demo projects](https://github.com/mybatis/jpetstore-6).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it was indeed a version issue, I chose the version as 3.x instead of 2.x when I created the springboot project, and after the change it works fine already!

Comment: Please, in the future choose tags for questions carefully. `spring-integration` is related to the specific project, not general concept of software connections: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-integration/info